# Where can I find a full list of all the Naruto Shippuden uncut box sets?

Tags: naruto, merchandise

Can anyone direct me to a site or does anyone have the full list of all the Naruto Shippuden uncut box sets. I have Season 1 box set 1, 3 , 4.
I am trying to buy all of them. I am hoping to NOT have to buy individual dvd's
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

There are currently **[26 Box Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes#Box_sets)** been released, the 27th Box Set will be released on July 5, 2016.

You can hang around on these websites to find the best price.

> [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/naruto-shippuden-box-set)
>   [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Naruto+Shippuden+box&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3ANaruto+Shippuden+box)
>   [Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/search/?query=naruto%20shippuden%20box)